# Is there any way to reduce the operations between these two dependent matrices?

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices where the first matrix is created from data from the second and is used to transform the second. I repeat this operation a large number of times. Due to the dependencies of these two matrices, I haven't been able to find a way to speed up the operations here. I'll try and show you what I'm talking about with a small matrix size.

```
[ 1 0 0     0     ]     [ .11 .22 .33 .44 ]
[ 0 1 0     0     ]     [ .65 .42 .01 .92 ]
[ 0 0 .51^2 .85^2 ]  *  [ .31 .15 .51 .85 ]
[ 0 0 .44^2 .23^2 ]     [ .25 .78 .44 .23 ]
        A                        B
```

Say I do this operation millions of times, and the position of the calculated values in A depend on where I want the rotation to occur in the B. So, in each iteration matrix A and B are different, and the values used to calculate the new values to be placed in A are different.

Does anyone know of a method to speed up this type of code? Considering the matrix multiply is essentially vector-matrix multiply I was hoping to create a combined A (unroll to the point where A is a full matrix, or full enough to take advantage of MMM algorithms), but the data dependence for the new values make it seem like I may be stuck. I get something like this:

```
A * B = B'
A' * B' = B''
A'' * B'' = B'''
```

where A' is derived from B', A'' from B'', and so on.

Edit:

To clarify, the second round could be:

```
[ 1 0     0     0 ]     [ .11 .22 .33 .44 ]
[ 0 .65^2 .42^2 0 ]     [ .65 .42 .01 .92 ]
[ 0 .26^2 .60^2 0 ]  *  [ .26 .60 .45 .39 ]
[ 0 0     0     1 ]     [ .06 .04 .10 .17 ]
        A'                       B'
```

Comment: Will A, A', A'', ..., always be of the form A = [I, 0; 0, X]? If so you should simplify the question to remove the top half of B and all but the lower diagonal block of A (e.g., B' = [B_top; X*B_bottom]).

Comment: No, A will not always be as shown. The four rotational elements could be anywhere along the diagonal.

Comment: Is the size of your matrix always going to be 4x4 or something much larger?

Comment: Furthermore, are there going to be exactly 2 rows/columns that are exactly 1 on the diagonal, or can that number increase?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Both matrices are very large. I was just using a smaller example. A starts as a very large Identity matrix and I write in the four values I want to use to transform matrix B. Those four values always straddle the diagonal as shown.

Comment: @user1362058: As I show in my answer below, if you have a `n`×`n` matrix `B`, and the elements in `A` on rows `r` and `r+1`, columns `c` and `c+1` are the corresponding elements in `B` squared, you can do the update in `4*n+4` multiplications and `2*n` additions using only `B` and no extra storage. Some compilers can vectorize it (for SSE/AVX/AVX2 etc.), but it is also possible to vectorize it by hand; this is likely to give almost a 2× (SSE/AVX) to 4× (AVX2) speedup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiplying matrix `A[rows][num]` by matrix `B[num][cols]`, each element in the resulting matrix `C[rows][cols]` is

```
C[r][c] = A[r][0]*B[0][c] + ... + A[r][num-1]*B[num-1][c]
        = sum( A[r][k] * B[k][c], k = 0 .. num-1 )
```

Here, `A` is an identity matrix except of two rows (`r0` and `r1`), which each have two values in two columns (`c0` and `c1`). Because rows `r0` and `r1` are otherwise zero, each element in the result matrix `C` on those rows is a sum of two products:

```
C[r0][i] = A[r0][c0] * B[c0][i] + A[r0][c1] * B[c1][i]
C[r1][i] = A[r1][c0] * B[c0][i] + A[r1][c1] * B[c1][i]
```

and since `A` is otherwise an identity matrix, all other rows in the result are the same as the corresponding row in the `B` matrix.

If we use

```
a00 = A[r0][c0]        a01 = A[r0][c1]
a10 = A[r1][c0]        a11 = A[r1][c1]
```

then we can describe the update loop as

```
For i = 0 .. cols-1
    C[r0][i] = a00 * B[c0][i] + a01 * B[c1][i]
    C[r1][i] = a10 * B[c0][i] + a11 * B[c1][i]
End for
```

If we use two temporary variables within the update loop (in case `c0 == r0` or `c1 == r0`, so that we do not overwrite the element at `[r0][i]` before we calculate the element at `[r1][i]`), the entire operation can be done in place, using only the `B` matrix.

If the non-identity elements in the left matrix `A` are the corresponding elements in matrix `B` squared, and we do the update in place, it becomes quite simple. In C99:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void update(const size_t n, double B[n][n], const size_t r, const size_t c)
{
    const double a00 = B[r  ][c  ] * B[r  ][c  ];
    const double a01 = B[r  ][c+1] * B[r  ][c+1];
    const double a10 = B[r+1][c  ] * B[r+1][c  ];
    const double a11 = B[r+1][c+1] * B[r+1][c+1];
    size_t       i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const double b0i = B[c  ][i];
        const double b1i = B[c+1][i];
        B[r  ][i] = a00 * b0i + a01 * b1i;
        B[r+1][i] = a10 * b0i + a11 * b1i;
    }
}
```

The computational cost of the above operation is `4*n+4` multiplications and `2*n` additions (of matrix elements), i.e. *O(N)*.

This approach is also applicable to [Givens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) and [Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_rotation) rotations, except that instead of calculating the four elements using the given matrix, they're calculated from a parameter passed to the function; and instead of consecutive rows and columns, two separate row and two column parameters needs to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a math issue than a programming issue, but yes there is a way to speed up your computations. This answer assumes that you are multiplying large matrices, but `A` is a slight modification on the identity matrix, only containing 4 changes at locations (`i,i`), (`i,i+1`), (`i+1,i`), and (`i+1,i+1`) as you have mentioned in the comments.

Note that multiplying `B` on the left by a matrix `A` where `A` has a row of all zeros except a 1 on the diagonal is equivalent to saying that the `i`th row of `AB` is equal to the `i`th row of B. This then means that you can immediately save a lot of computation in your iterations.

Given the update `B' = A*B` where `A` has these nice properties, we have the following algorithm:

1. Initialize `B'` to be exactly `B`.
2. Perform the matrix multiplication `update = [A(i,:),A(i+1,:)]*B`, where this left hand side is a `(2xn)` matrix.
3. Store the output of this update in the correct two rows of `B'`: `[B'(i,:),B'(i+1,:)]`.

Flops every update = `O(2n^2)`

---

If your size `n` is truly massive, you might want to save more computations in these small matrix multiplications by taking advantage of the row sparsity of the two rows of `A` as well. Instead of performing a `(2xn)` by `(nxn)` matrix multiplication, you could perform a `(2x2)` by `(2xn)` matrix multiplication.

This new algorithm will again update the correct two rows of `B'`. However, now your update matrix multiplication only has to be:

```
update = [A(i  ,i), A(i  ,i+1)] * [B(i  ,:)]
         [A(i+1,i), A(i+1,i+1)]   [B(i+1,:)]
```

Flops every update = `O(4n)`

---

Note that neither algorithm explicitly stores all of `A`, so you will be saving on memory as well as computation. Also, both preceding algorithms will be very cache efficient if you are storing your matrix in row-major format.